# Identifying specific words in text

Tags: text-mining, text, text-filter

Let's say I have the following text"

> Is that another kitten playing in the shoes in the top right?

I would like my code to extract `kitten` from that text.

Is there any list of animals names readily available?

Answer (score 0):

I don‘t know why this question was downvoted. Anyway, this might help you: 
https://gist.github.com/atduskgreg/3cf8ef48cb0d29cf151bedad81553a54

or this: https://github.com/hzlzh/Domain-Name-List/blob/master/Animal-words.txt

Always check github for such things...

Comment: Thanks a lot! really helpful

Comment: @william: happy to help, a vote is appreciated

Comment: `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.` I get this :(